# How to include Matplot++ in CodeBlocks

Tags: cmake, codeblocks

I recently discovered the [Matplot++ library](https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus), a clear equivalent of the classical matplotlib, available for Python, but for C++. I would love to use it but so far I have not found a way to install/include it in my project. I am using Code::Blocks and the library seems to require cmake commands, can somebody help me here? Is there any way to include this library within my project?

Thank you for your help!
Sergio

I have downloaded the library ZIP file and include it under the Compiler/Search directories/Compiler & Linker tabs but I get a lot of "No such file or directory" errors.

Comment: I could give you some suggestions:1, Please post a full Build log with full command lines. 2, Could you Please try to add those Source files to your cb project? Matplot++ library should be compiled, too. 3, CMake can generate CodeBlocks makefiles, Maybe you can try. In addition, you can ask in [CodeBlocks Forums](https://Forums.CodeBlocks.org)for more exact information, and don't forget to look for questions in [CodeBlocks wiki](https://wiki.CodeBlocks.org)first.